# Активация button при наличии данных во всех input

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте создал форму отправки письма. Заказчик хочет сделать так, чтобы кнопка отправки становилась активной, если во все полях ввести данные. Если в одном из input  данные удалить, то кнопка деактивировалась.
Пытался написать что-то аналогичное найденному на просторах рунета, но проверяться ввод в реальном времени не хочет.

Решение желательно на чистом js, ибо jquery не хочется подключать.
И хотелось бы не навешивать классы на каждый инпут, если это возможно, для обращения к ним.

html:

```
<input type="text" value="111" />
<input type="text" value="111" />
<input type="text" />
<button>test</button>
```

js:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
function test() {
  for (i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].value == '') {
      button.disabled = true;
    } else {
      button.disabled = false;
    };
  };  
};
// input.onchange = test();
input.onkeyup = test();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')),
button = document.querySelector('button');

inputs.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('input', checkInputs, false);
});
function checkInputs(){
 var empty = inputs.filter(function(el){
    return el.value.trim() === '';
  }).length;
  button.disabled = empty !== 0;
}
checkInputs();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="111" />
<input type="text" value="111" />
<input type="text" />
<button>test</button>
```