# Проверка пустых полей ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма

```
<form method="post" id="orderForm">
<input type=text>
<input type=phone>
<input type=email id=email>
<input type=button id=submit_f>
</form>

$("#submit_f").click(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();


    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/validation/email_validate.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {email: email, type: 'checkEmail'},
        success: function(data){
           $('form#orderForm').trigger( 'reset' );
            if(data == "ok"){
              $('#submit_f').prop('disabled', true);
                $('form#orderForm').submit();

            } else {
                swal("Пользователь с таким email уже существует", "", "error");
            }
        }
    })
});
```

По нажатию на кнопку `submit`, происходит проверка имеется ли введенный email в базе. А как добавить проверку на пустоту оставшиеся `input`. Т.к. пришлось изменить `type=submite` на `type=button` `required` не работает.

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475529/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-button-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-input)

Comment: используй $("#orderForm").submit();

Comment: if(input.value.length === 0) //пустой input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант можно так, если вставить до $.ajax().

Но можно **(желательно)** запихнуть в $.ajax().beforeSend();

```
var  send = true;
$('form#orderForm input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val() || $(this).val() == ''){
       $(this).css('border-color','red');//Сделаем бордер красным
       send = false;
    }
});

if(!send) return false;
//всё что ниже не выполнится пока send будет false
```